# How to handle a JSONP callback using jQuery?

Tags: jquery, api, jsonp, flickr

I am using jQuery to make ajax calls to the [flickr API](http://www.flickr.com/services/feeds/).

So far, I have made a successful call to the [public photos](http://www.flickr.com/services/feeds/docs/photos_public/) API and displayed the results. Here is the jQuery that I used:

```
getPics = function(){
    $.ajax({
        url: 'http://api.flickr.com/services/feeds/photos_public.gne?format=json&jsoncallback=callbackForImages',
        dataType: 'jsonp'
    });
}
callbackForImages = function(data){
    clearResults();
    $.each(data.items, function(i, item) {
        $("<img/>").attr("src", item.media.m).appendTo("#results");
    });
}
```

However when I try to use the [forums API](http://www.flickr.com/services/feeds/docs/forums/), I'm not sure how to format the callback function.

Here is what I have so far.

```
getTopics = function(){
    $.ajax({
        url: 'http://api.flickr.com/services/feeds/forums.gne?format=json&jsoncallback=callbackForTopics',
        dataType: 'jsonp'
    });
}

callbackForTopics = function(data){
    clearResults();
    //this is the bit that's broken
    $.each(data.items, function()) {
        $("title").value.appendTo("#results");
    }
}

clearResults = function(){
    $("#results").html('<div id="results"></div>');
}
```

Any help in understanding how to use the returned JSONP would be appreciated.

Comment: `callbackForTopics = function(){` should be `callbackForTopics = function(data){`

Comment: Thanks Joy. I made the change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fetch part seems wrong. Try something like

```
$.each(data.items, function(idx,val) {
   $("#results").append($('<div></div>').text(val.title));
});
```

example: http://jsfiddle.net/Y9Jj3/2/

Answer (score 1):

The difference between the first piece of code:

```
callbackForImages = function(data){
```

And second piece of code:

```
callbackForTopics = function(){
```

You're missing the `data` parameter in the function definition.

Also, this is weird:

```
$("title").value.appendTo("#results");
```

Not sure what you meant there, but this won't work for sure.

Btw, this can be easily caught using the browser developer tools (e.g. Firebug)

Comment: I didn't notice the missing parameter, although that doesn't fix it. The line that you highlighted as 'weird' is the one I'm having trouble with. I just put it in to show what I'd tried. Essentially, what I want it to do is to show the title of each item returned in the div with id="results".

Answer (score 0):

I figured out what to do thanks to the answers provided by Jack and Sofl. My callback method should have been as follows:

```
callbackForTopics = function(data){
    clearResults();
    $.each(data.items, function(i, item) {
        $("#results").append($('<div></div>').text(item.title));
    });
}
```